# Pip install-couldn't find a version that satisfies the requirement

Tags: python, package, installation, pip

I am trying to install a package called [got](https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets-python) using pip. But it keeps showing up errors of 'couldn't find a version that satisfies the requirement".

[image: error]

I've searched online about the solutions. There are some explanation saying to try pip freeze > requirements.txt. But it still remains a blackbox to me.

What is the problem here and what should I do exactly to install the package?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to install [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/got/0.1.0)? It looks like it may not exist any more.

Comment: You can find it here https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets-python

Comment: Are you sure they put it in pypi? I can't find it. I don't think it's a library that you install.

Comment: It's probably not in pypi, like Morgan Thrapp was asking you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your package `got` is indeed not on Pypi.

Your error is thrown when no package have been found.

eg:

```
→ pip install notfoundpackage
Collecting notfoundpackage
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement notfoundpackage (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for notfoundpackage
```

Though, because you know the github link, you can clone the repository using git.

```
git clone git@github.com:Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets-python.git
cd GetOldTweets-python
python Exporter.py -h
```

If you really need a python library for tweeter, some other library already exist, like [twython](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython/tree/master).

Comment: `twython` and `tweepy`are both pretty good, but they use both the Twitter API, so they are unfortunately very limited in terms of all kind of use. With `got` you can get very old tweets and you can get much more tweets in at once.

Answer (score 3):

This package doesn't include a `setup.py`, so you can't install it from pip.

If it did, you could install it with:

`pip install git+https://github.com/Jefferson-Henrique/GetOldTweets-python.git`

Answer (score 1):

This could be a proxy setting issue (it was in my case). Ensure that you have correct proxies set, if you are behind a firewall.