# error in running `pip install aws cli`: "could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cli"

Tags: amazon-web-services, pip, git-bash

I'm on a Windows based machine using GitBash for my shell.  When I run, `pip install aws cli`, I get the following message:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cli (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for cli

I Googled the error, and many responses indicate that it's can be the result of a package that's not contained in pypi, etc. ([Pip install-couldn't find a version that satisfies the requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38903415/pip-install-couldnt-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement)).

However, since I'm following the video here: http://course.fast.ai/lessons/aws.html at 4:13, and it worked for the instructor, I'm not sure what I'm missing - can someone help me understand this (including any helpful troubleshooting commands to identify the source of the issue?)

I'm new to AWS and also bash so I apologize if this is a relatively elementary question.

Thanks in advance! 
-Ryan

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The command should be:

```
pip install awscli
```

You need to remove the space between 'aws' and 'cli'.

Comment: Thank you, very much appreciated.  This command was covered up in the video link I provided by the video title "AWS Deep Learning setup" which is why I didn't notice that there shouldn't be a space.  Thanks again.

Comment: FYI, the AWS Certified  Developer Official Study Guide gives instructions for installing and configuring AWS CLI and they list it with a dash too (pg. 28). It must have changed at some point.

Comment: @MiriamP.Raphael I'm not sure that the Python package was ever called `aws-cli` with a dash. It could just be a typo in that guide.

Comment: @Alasdair Very possible

Answer (score 1):

Try these commands

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py

python get-pip.py
```

then

```
pip install awscli
```